# How come 0^0 = 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider this:

```
0^0 = 1
0^1 = 0
0^2 = 0
0^n = 0 (for int n > 0)
```

So how come `0^0 = 1`, how can you get something out of nothing? Isn't it a mathematical heresy?

Also what does it mean to raise something to the power of `0`?
Like `2^2 = 2 * 2 = 4`, I understand that, but what `2^0=?` in that case?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says $0^0$ is *indeterminate*. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%5E0

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is smart... my calculator is not so much )

Comment: What's amazing is that after being closed, two more answers were posted! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Simple, you are absolutely right. $0^0$ *is not defined*, it doesn't really make sense.

But on the other hand, it is often handy to take $0^0=1$. For example, if you write a polynomial as:
$$
p(x) = \sum_{0 \le k \le n} a_k x^k
$$
you want to have $p(0) = a_0$, i.e., you are implicitly taking $0^0 = 1$. In other situations it is nice to take $0^0  = 0$. Just be careful.

There have been several threads here on this subject, look around.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the limit of $x^x$ as $x$ goes to zero, that comes out to 1. That's one rationale for letting $0^0$ equal 1. For nonzero $x$, $x^0 = x^1/x = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$0^0$ is not necessarily equal to $1$, it is indeterminate, at least in the context of Algebra and Calculus. Take for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/811145/10245), as an example of why $0^0$ stays undefined when it comes up in Algebra and Calculus. If you take a limit that appears to approach $0^0$, and we were to define $0^0=1$, we might end up with something like $1=\frac12$.

Comment: In set theory, or related fields $0^0$ is **absolutely equal to $1$**. Because it's defined as the cardinality of $\varnothing^\varnothing=\{\varnothing\}$, which is precisely $1$.

Comment: @Asaf - fair enough. I edited my answer to specify that it is undefined specifically for the purposes of algebra and calculus.